# Intalling libqwt6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, qwt

Good Day to you,

I have a program to install which needs the library libqwt6. I am installing it using a .deb package. In previous versions of Ubuntu, it seems that this library could be installed with a simple apt-get but for my version, no package correspond to that name.

So I tried to install the library by first installing QT to then be able to install [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/#installonmainpage). After having done that, I have a file libqwt.so on my disk. I added it to the dynamic linker but the system still cannot find it. When I look for libqwt with :

```
ldconfig -p | grep libqwt
```

I get

```
libqwt6 (libc6)
```

Does anyone have a simple solution to install this library? Would returning to an older version of Ubuntu be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 has packages for qwt.

Qt4 version is named `libqwt6abi1` (development headers: `libqwt-dev`)

Qt5 version is named `libqwt-qt5-6` (development headers: `libqwt-qt5-dev`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already installed those libraries but when I want to install my program I still get the error:

Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libqwt6 (>= 6.0.0).

Comment: Are you trying to install 'your program' from a debian package?

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry I'm new to this. I should have specified that

Comment: Well, even if you manage to install qwt yourself, you haven't installed the debian package called `libqwt6` so you won't be able to install another debian package that depends on it. Installing a library from source as you did, and installing a debian package is different. You can try installing your program with `dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libqwt6 yourpackage.deb`, this will ignore the dependency but the application may not work (probably will crash) if it's not compatible with the installed qwt library. In this case building the application itself from source is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a file e.g. `qwtlib.conf` with a row <*path to your libqwt.so*> (e.g. `/usr/local/qwt-6.0.2/lib`) to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and then run `ldconfig` in there, with root privileges?